# Javascript search widget with add/remove criteria

Tags: javascript, search

I'm looking for a FOSS Javascript widget which allows you to add/remove search criteria using a GUI.

My basis is the search criteria in Mac OS X Finder, but I know I've seen similar systems elsewhere:

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/579/screenshot20100429at805.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/579/screenshot20100429at805.png)

The basic idea is that each row corresponds to one field in your database, and depending on the type of that field you would get different search options when you select it. You click the + and - buttons to add or remove fields.

Anybody aware of something like this that's already out there? Preferably written to work with YUI, but I don't mind transliterating from a JQuery or Dojo widget.

Comment: What server side language/DB are you working with? You'll need to tie the bits together to make this work... the UI bit is actually pretty simple.

Comment: PHP+MySQL, using Doctrine and Zend Framework.

Comment: For anybody interested, I ended up writing my own implementation in YUI. It *is* open source, but it's not pretty. Contact me directly if you would like a pointer to the source.

Comment: Could you answer your own question on SO with a link to your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lukecyca asked me to post a link to my implementation. This was written for an open source (GPL) project sponsored by a company that I no longer work for, so I can't guarantee that these links will stay up, but here goes.

[image: screen shot of search feature]

The source code is currently on BitBucket. There's [a client side (Javascript) library](https://bitbucket.org/openfisma-ondemand/openfisma/src/594168569fd90f07e8614afdcfa36c77bc69720c/public/javascripts/Fisma/Search?at=master) that is probably what you're most interested in, but there's also [a server side (PHP) component](https://bitbucket.org/openfisma-ondemand/openfisma/src/594168569fd90f07e8614afdcfa36c77bc69720c/library/Fisma/Search?at=master) that may be useful. It's pretty messy code (tightly coupled and really rushed), so I'm not sure it will even be useful, but there is [a bit of documentation to help explain it](https://openfisma.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PUBLIC/Search). It's also been modified quite a bit since I left.

There's [a demo server](http://openfisma.org/demo) that's usually running if you want to see it in action. Please note that the username and password for the demo are listed on that page.